# Does Mixpanel Analytics for Android work when offline?

Tags: android, mixpanel

I know that flurry tracks offline data from android sessions but I want to try mixpanel. Has anybody used mixpanel for offline apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked on the Android library at Mixpanel, and I can tell you that we will safely queue up your Mixpanel data when there is no Internet connection available. It will be sent out the next time an Internet connection is available.

Comment: how long can you stay offline? or how many bytes can you store to queue data offline?

Comment: No it doesn't work for me when the app goes offline.

Comment: @AnluWang is there any limit of queue up the data in terms of time or size of data?